# How to run animation backwards when its finished

Tags: flutter

I have this simple animation of a line that goes from bottom to top of my container:

```
void didChangeDependencies() {
    animationController = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);
    double firstPosition = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2) - (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2);
    double lastPosition = (firstPosition + MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * proporcaoScaner) - (espessuraContornos + esperruraLinha);
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: firstPosition, end: lastPosition).animate(animationController)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    animationController.forward();
```

And I want it to run backwards once it reach the lastPosition, I tried `animationController.repeat()` but it just jump back to first position. I've also tried to make it conditional:

```
if (animationController.isCompleted) {
      animationController.reverse();
    } else {
      animationController.forward();
    }
```

But it just stops on lastPosition.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working, but I don't know it its the best aproach.

```
void didChangeDependencies() {
    animationController = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);
    double firstPosition = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2) - (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2);
    double lastPosition = (firstPosition + MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * proporcaoScaner) - (espessuraContornos + esperruraLinha);
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: firstPosition, end: lastPosition).animate(animationController);

    animationController.addListener(() {
      if (animationController.isCompleted) {
        setState(() {
          animationController.reverse();
        });
      }
      if (animationController.isDismissed) {
        setState(() {
          animationController.forward();
        });
      }
      setState(() {

      });
    });

    animationController.forward();

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```